# Multiple HTTP methods display for the spring fox health route in swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-boot-actuator

I have use spring boot actuator health with spring fox swagger in a spring boot projet. I use below in my Application.java class.

```
@Autowired
private HealthAggregator healthAggregator;

@Autowired
private Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators;

@Bean
public com.health.TestMeHealthEndpoint getHealthEndpoint() {
    return new com.health.TestMeHealthEndpoint(healthAggregator, healthIndicators);
}

@Bean
public Docket testMeApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).useDefaultResponseMessages(false).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
            .paths(testMePaths()).build();
}

private Predicate<String> testMePaths() {
    return or(regex("/api/myservice1"), regex("/health"));
}
```

But when I check the swagger ui, I see multiple end points for health with all types of http methods include POST,DELETE, OPTIONS etc. For myservice1 which implement in the REST contoller, it only display the GET method.

The TestMeHealthEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint and overide invoke method with custom health information.

I only want to see is the GET method for the health route?

Add source of TestMeHealthEndpoint:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "endpoints.health", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
public class TestMeHealthEndpoint  extends AbstractEndpoint<Health> {

  //Some getter and setters for api name , version etc

  public TestMeHealthEndpoint (final HealthAggregator healthAggregator,
            final Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators) {
        super("health", false);
        final CompositeHealthIndicator healthIndicator = new CompositeHealthIndicator(healthAggregator);
        for (final Map.Entry<String, HealthIndicator> entry : healthIndicators.entrySet()) {
            healthIndicator.addHealthIndicator(getKey(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
        }
        this.healthIndicator = healthIndicator;
    }

  @Override
    public Health invoke() {
        final Health health = new Health();
        health.setStatus(this.healthIndicator.health().getStatus().getCode());
        health.setName(this.apiName);
        health.setVersion(this.apiVersion);
        final UriComponentsBuilder path = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentServletMapping()
                .path(this.managementContextPath).pathSegment(this.getId());
        health.add(new Link(path.build().toUriString()).withSelfRel());
        return health;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the source code TestMeHealthEndpoint

Comment: @shazin Please fine the edit question

Comment: what is this AbstractEndpoint? Which framework are you using?

Comment: spring boot actuator

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you a little workaround. To create rest controller which will be delegate requests to the Health endpoint. Something like this:

```
@RestController
public class HealthController {

    @Autowired
    TestMeHealthEndpoint testMeHealthEndpoint;

    @ApiOperation(value="Health endpoint", notes = "Health endpoint")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/health", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")})
    public ResponseEntity<Health> invoke() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testMeHealthEndpoint.invoke());
    }
}
```

In that way you also can use following directive for swagger:

```
.select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

Swagger assumes that if no `@RequestMapping` method is set, any method is ok. Add `method = RequestMethod.GET` to your `RequestMapping` braces `()`.

> f you add a @Bean of type Endpoint then it will automatically be exposed over JMX and HTTP (if there is an server available). An HTTP endpoints can be customized further by creating a bean of type MvcEndpoint. Your MvcEndpoint is not a @Controller but it can use @RequestMapping (and @Managed*) to expose resources.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: TestMeHealthEndpoint  is not a RestController know. So I cant add it

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: IF i just use the spring actuator default health route only with pom dependency, it only shows UP when hit the /health endpoint. But I need to add additional data such as api name, version so that I have to implement a TestMeHealthEndpoint